# pysftp SFTP file transfert is being suspended after 30MB

Tags: python-2.7, pysftp

I'am trying to transfer files from SFTP to Local and for some reasons, the transfer of files with more then 30MB is suspended automatically when acheiving the 27-28 MB without getting any error message.

This is my code :

```
    for entry in sftp.listdir_attr(remoteFilePath):
        filepath = remoteFilePath + '/' + entry.filename
        sftp.get(filepath, os.path.join(localFilePath, entry.filename))
        sftp.remove(filepath)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this is the solution :

```
with sftp.open(filepath, "rb") as fr, \
     open(os.path.join(localFilePath, entry.filename), "wb") as fl:
    while True:
        data = fr.read(1024)
        fl.write(data)
        if len(data) == 0:
            break
```